# Uploading and Saving the Video file using Parse API was unsuccessful in Android

Tags: android, parse-platform

**-** I am using `Parse` api to **upload and save** the video file to the `Parse.com` Server for an application.

**- I am at present using the following code from Parse Documentation to upload the video file to the Parse Server:**

```
    File f = new File("/sdcard/video-2013-02-21-13-03-24.mp4");

    byte[] videoUp = IOUtils.toByteArray( new FileInputStream(f));


    ParseFile file = new ParseFile("testVideo1", videoUp);




    file.saveInBackground(new SaveCallback() {


        public void done(ParseException e) {

      e.printStackTrace();

     }

     }, new ProgressCallback() {

     public void done(Integer percentDone) {

     System.out.println("Progress :" + percentDone);
      }
     });
```

**-** At **first** its printing **progress 100 %** which is the resultant of `System.out.println` statement from `done()` method with `Integer` as parameter, and immediately **after that** its going into the method `done()` with `ParseException` as the parameter printing the following stack trace.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.uploadfileusingparse.MainActivity$1$1.done(MainActivity.java:63)
at com.parse.SaveCallback.internalDone(SaveCallback.java:42)
at com.parse.SaveCallback.internalDone(SaveCallback.java:29)
at com.parse.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:50)
at com.parse.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:16)
at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:417)
at android.os.AsyncTask.access$300(AsyncTask.java:127)
at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:429)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4633)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:858)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**-** `Parse` has given detailed tutorials and info about the `IPhone` Integration, but i **didn't** find any tutorial explaining that in `Android`.

**-** Can anyone please give me a **tutorial** explaining the **integration** of `Parse` Api into the application to **upload the multimedia files to the Parse Server.**

Comment: There is a NPE on MainActivity.java, line 63. Set a break-point, find out *what* is `null` and *why* it is.

Comment: Null Pointer exception is thrown after the progress goes to 100%, now why after the upload the video file is not getting saved is the question here, and offcourse i can't trace whats going on, on the server side............I would appreciate if someone can provide a working solution to this

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the error because you are trying to call a method from a null variable. If the saveInBackground() is successful by right the ParseException in done(ParseException e) will be null. Fix it by doing a check if the ParseException is null:

```
  public void done(ParseException e) {
      if(e==null) {
          // SUCCESS!!!
      } else {
          e.printStackTrace();
      }
  }
```

This applies to all ParseObject methods with names ending with *inBackground